# How to find the longest common prefix in an array of strings?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve this using the .every method but it's not returning true and therefore it's not adding onto my string and I'm not sure why.

```js
var longestCommonPrefix = function(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr.every(x => arr[i].charAt(i) === x)) {
      result += arr[i].charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(longestCommonPrefix(["flower", "flow", "flight"])); //fl
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to iterate over *one* string, not over the whole array: check if the first character of the string is present everywhere, then the second character, etc:

```js
var longestCommonPrefix = function(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    if (arr.every(x => x.charAt(i) === arr[0][i])) {
      result += arr[i].charAt(i);
    } else break;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(longestCommonPrefix(["flower", "flow", "flight"])); //fl
```

Comment: code contains bug, `result += arr[i].charAt(i);` should be `result += arr[0].charAt(i);`

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `Array.every` is along the right lines. You want to check that every string in the array has the same character at position `i`. I think you got confused when you named the parameter `x`, when it is in fact a string :)

```js
var longestCommonPrefix = function(words) {
  if (words.length === 0) {
    return "";
  }
  
  const letters = [];
  const lengthOfShortestWord = Math.min(...words.map(word => word.length));
  
  for (let i = 0; i < lengthOfShortestWord; i++) {
    const char = words[0][i];
    if (words.every(word => word[i] === char)) {
      letters.push(char);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return letters.join("");
}

console.log(longestCommonPrefix(["flower", "flow", "flight"])); //fl
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am mistaken the longest prefix is never going to be greater than the smallest string in the array.

In this case `"fl"` is both the *smallest* string and the *longest* common prefix:

```js
["flower", "fl", "flight"]
```

So start with finding the smallest string in `arr`:

```js
let [sm] = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
```

Then check that all strings in `arr` start with `sm`:

```js
arr.every(str => str.startsWith(sm));
```

If that isn't the case then shorten `sm` by one character:

```js
sm = sm.slice(0, -1);
```

And keep going until you eventually find the longest prefix or `sm` becomes an empty string:

```js
const prefix = arr => {
  let [sm] = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
  while (sm && !arr.every(str => str.startsWith(sm))) sm = sm.slice(0, -1);
  return sm;
};
```